# Why github pages does not load my page?

Tags: github, dns

I have uploaded a page on github and it was successful. However, when I set the DNS number, the page does not load and it gives the following message:

`This site can’t be reached
example.net’s server DNS address could not be found.`

But, the real problem is that the page with the address: `myuser.github.io` loads properly on every other device except the one I set the DNS!!! When I type: `myuser.github.io` on my PC, it redirects to my custom domain `example.net` and the above message appears.

While in every other device I check, `myuser.github.io`, loads properly without redirecting to my custom domain.

Any comment is really appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by `when I set the DNS number`? What number, where?

Answer (score 0):

> when I set the DNS number

It is possible, [as illustrated in this issue](https://github.com/mozilla/thimble.mozilla.org/issues/1463#issuecomment-203039333), that the DNS you set is not yet refreshed to include `example.net`.

Try setting the Google DNS for testing.